# CodeIgniter Database result align not proper

Tags: codeigniter

I got the result from database and trying to display on page. but alignment is not correct. may i know how can i fix it?

### **Code  in View**

```
<?php

        echo "<table align='center'>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>  Language ID:  </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> Language Name:  </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> Date Posted :  </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        if ($query == true) {
            foreach ($query as $row) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row -> pk_bint_language_id . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row -> vchr_language_name . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row -> bint_language_level . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row -> dat_updated_date . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";

            }

        }

        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I assume `Language Id, Language Name` are headers, correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display `four` rows within the `foreach` loop, however you have only `three` in the header section. From what I can see you are missing `Language level` /added to the example/

```
 echo "<table align='center'>
          <tr>
            <td> Language ID:  </td>
            <td> Language Name:  </td>
            <td> Language Level:  </td>
            <td> Date Posted :  </td>
          </tr>";

    if ($query == true) {
        foreach ($query as $row) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row -> pk_bint_language_id . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row -> vchr_language_name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row -> bint_language_level . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row -> dat_updated_date . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have **3** `<td>`s in the first table row (`<tr>`) with the static "Language ID:" and such, but you have **4** `<td>`s inside the `foreach()` loop. It seems like you are missing the "Language level" from the static `<td>`s.

I would recommend to use the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should use table header `th` instead of `td`. At least it is a more proper way.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can check that on w3school http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

@bborisovs answer is correct . But if you want to use 3 td instead of four you can also do like this

```
<td colspan="2"> //meainng this single 'td' with take two 'td' place
```